# use webdriver.io .click() inside of a .isVisible function - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: node.js, click, webdriver-io

I use node js, selenium server standalone with chromedriver and webdriver.io

I want to say that if buttonxyz `.isVisible` or `.isExisting` that my script is using `.click()` on it. If the button does not exist the function will be ignored.

so `webdriver.io` told me this

```
client.isExisting('#someRandomNonExistingElement').then(function(isExisting) {
        console.log(isExisting); // outputs: false
})
```

I want a structure like this

```
client.isExisting('#someRandomNonExistingElement').then(function(isExisting) {
        client.click('#someRandomNonExistingElement')
})
```

But it´s not working for me. the script stops on pages where the buttons don't exist and if the CSS selector is existing the function does not work.

Then I tried something like

```
.isExisting('.buttoncsshere').click('buttoncsshere')
```

Well with this code it clicks on the button if it exist, but if the button not exist the script stop working. Sorry I´am a newbie code girl can you help me pls

EDIT: this was the solution for me

```
.isVisible('css').then(function(isVisible) {

    if (isVisible) {
        client
        .click('css')
        .pause(1000)
    } 
})
```

Comment: well this worked for me 

 .isVisible('css').then(function(isVisible) {
  
  if (isVisible) {
   client
   .click('css')
   .pause(1000)
  } 
 })

Answer (score 1):

Using pause() compromises the robustness of your tests. Especially if you have network latency issues. You really should be using `waitForVisible`. http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitForVisible.html

```
client.waitForVisible('css')
      .click('css')
```